# Already dead process is continuing to eat net traffic

Tags: process, internet-connection, netstat, traffic

I'm using Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.2, SciTE, Outpost Pro 2009 and NetBalancer.

Wrinting Ruby programs in SciTE I press `Ctrl+Break` to kill them. This way is designed to be easy, quick and reliable. But now I wrote a kind of program I never wrote before and found a problem.

Program crowls a website in 10 threads (`Thread.new`) with `open-uri`. Each thread downloads one small file. Some urls have `Timeout::Error`.
When I press `Ctrl+Break`, process `ruby.exe` dies (I can see it in Task Manager also) and SciTE is ready for the next `F5`. Outpost also doesn't show me any net activity.
BUT! The NetBalancer's icon in tray shows, that my net is maximally loaded – 512kbps. When I open NetBalancer I see green line, showing net load, but there is no traffic-eating process in list, so I don't know what should I kill to stop it.
And when I do `netstat -o`, I see this:

```
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53629      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_1      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53630      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53631      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53632      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53648      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53664      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53667      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
  TCP    192.168.1.2:53676      server2:http           FIN_WAIT_2      916
```

Seems like I have just to use `taskkill`, but:

```
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /PID 916
Ошибка: Не удается найти процесс "916".
```

*(Translation: Can't find process "916")*

Invisible process continues to eat all my net channel for several minutes and then stops. Connections in `netstat` also dissapear. But I even don't understand how, why and when does it stop, because the full downloading task should last near an hour. So it dies spontaneously?
Anyway I want to have a way to kill this invisible *net-eaters*.

Answer (score 3):

When the process exits, Windows requests the server to close the TCP connection by sending a FIN packet. However, since your connection is being used at 100%, the FIN packet takes some time to reach the server. During that time, the server doesn't know about the process death and sends *even more* data to you. The `FIN-WAIT` state means your computer sent a FIN packet and is waiting for an acknowledging FIN+ACK.

The process is already dead; you're seeing its PID because the PID is stored along with other TCP connection parameters, and the connection hasn't been closed yet.